# Interpolating Z at polyline vertices between known Zs

Tags: qgis, line, interpolation, elevation, z-value

I have polyline strings with vertices of known elevation / z height and intermediate vertices with null/zero height. Known Zs are spread throughout the line.  I'd like to be able to populate the z of the intermediate vertices by linear interpolation between those known points.

I think this is functionality in Arc using IZ.InterpolateZsBetween?  Unable to verify due to no Arc access. Seeking functionality in QGIS or any alternative open package?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and would love some hints, too.

Answer (score 3):

Z-values can be added to the vertices of lines by an operation called [drape](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster). This is normally done from a raster. Thus we have to get a raster, containing the interpolated z-values. What is a bit tricky: You can't have `NULL` values for z, they are automatically set to `0`. So if you have vertex1 with z=100, vertex2 z=0 and vertex3 z=200, you probably want z for vertex 2 to be 150. So we first have to replace values of `0` with the mean of the value before and after this vertex.

The whole workflow looks as this:

1. Extract the vertices from you line using [Menu Vector / Geomtry Tools / Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices).
2. On the extracted vertices, create a new field called `z` using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator). Use the following expression - it checks if the z-value is `0` and in this case, it interpolates the z-value between the last and the next point (creating the mean of the two z-values, see screenshot at the bottom):

   ```
    if (
        z($geometry) =0, 
        (z(geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id-1)))+z(geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1))))/2,
        z($geometry)
    )
   ```
3. Create a [buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html#buffer-vectors) around your points with a size so that they do not overlap.
4. [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-overwrite-with-attribute) the buffers and set the field `z` (calculated in step 2) as `Field to use for a burn-in-value`.
5. Use [Menu Processing / Toolbox / Drape (set Z value from raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster) with your initial line as input and the raster from step 4 as raster layer. This will add the values from the raster (that correspond to the interpolated z-values from step 2) as new z-values to your line.

You can now densify your line using [Densify by inerval](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#densify-by-interval): thus adding additional vertices. z-values are then automatically interpolated.

[image]